# How to specify assembler flavor in gcc

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm

I am compiling a program for an embedded ARM device, and want to switch from one bootloader to another. Both bootloaders are written in assembler (for the same type of device), but the problem is that they are different dialects/flavors (perhaps Intel vs AT&T?). The existing assembler code compiles happily in gcc, but the one I want to use does not.

For example, the existing (working) code looks like this...

```
    /* Comments are c-style */
    .syntax unified
    .arch armv7-m
    .section .stack
    .align 3
#ifdef __STACK_SIZE
    .equ    Stack_Size, __STACK_SIZE
#else
    .equ    Stack_Size, 0xc00
#endif
    .globl    __StackTop
    .globl    __StackLimit
__StackLimit:
    .space    Stack_Size
    .size __StackLimit, . - __StackLimit
__StackTop:
    .size __StackTop, . - __StackTop
```

... and the code I want to use looks like this ...

```
; comments are lisp-style
Stack_Size      EQU     0x00000400
                AREA    STACK, NOINIT, READWRITE, ALIGN=3
Stack_Mem       SPACE   Stack_Size
__initial_sp
; <h> Heap Configuration
;   <o>  Heap Size (in Bytes) <0x0-0xFFFFFFFF:8>
; </h>  
Heap_Size       EQU     0x00000200
                AREA    HEAP, NOINIT, READWRITE, ALIGN=3
__heap_base
Heap_Mem        SPACE   Heap_Size
__heap_limit
                PRESERVE8
                THUMB
```

Notice the order of operands, and commenting style is different. What type of assembler is this second block? Can gcc be told to expect this format and parse it?

Comment: AT&T vs. Intel syntax applies only to x86 and not ARM. Like @unixsmurf states in his answer, your example contains only assembler directives and symbol definitions but no actual ARM instructions. The unified ARM / Thumb syntax for instructions is actually the same in the two assemblers.

Comment: The comments are in C style in the first example because the .S file is first passed through the C preprocessor as you can see from the #ifdef directives. gas uses '@' as the line comment character for ARM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first looks like AT&T to me, and the second like Intel. I don't think GCC has an option to change what flavor it uses (as it runs all of it's assembly through `GAS` (GNU assembler), which uses AT&T). But, if you spend a little time learning the C calling conventions, you can use NASM (Netwide Assembler, which uses Intel syntax but can't be inline). Just create a definition something like this in one of your C headers:

```
extern void assembly_boot();
```

And then in your assembly, implement it (yes, the prefixing underscore is correct):

```
global _assembly_boot
_assembly_boot:
  ;Blah blah blah
```

Note: That example doesn't implement the C calling conventions. If you want your assembly to be callable from C, you need to use the C calling conventions. Google them.

Answer (score 4):

The first one is GNU gas syntax, the second is ARM's commercial toolchain syntax.

The formats (directives and label definitions) are not compatible, although the instruction syntax itself is. Assembling the one with the other is not possible, but the generated object files can be linked together.

Your code examples contain no instructions however, only various assembler directives allocating space for stack and heap.